# Need more humane completion of environment variables

Tags: bash, bash-completion

Suppose we have this environment:

```
mkdir -p /tmp/foo/bar/
export TEST=/tmp/foo
```

Out of the box, bash completion of $TEST is extremely inconsistent. Witness: →

```
$ cd $TES<Tab>     →  $ cd $TEST<cursor>
$ cd $TEST<Tab>    →  $ cd $TEST<cursor>
$ cd $TEST/<Tab>   →  $ cd $TEST/<cursor> 
$ cd $TEST/b<Tab>  →  $ cd $TEST/b<cursor>        # no actual completion!
```

---

```
$ ls $TES<Tab>     →  $ ls $TES<cursor>           # no actual completion!
$ ls $TEST<Tab>    →  $ ls $TEST<cursor>          # same
$ ls $TEST/<Tab>   →  $ ls /tmp/foo/bar/<cursor>  # expands var, annoying!
```

---

```
$ echo $TES<Tab>   →  $ echo $TEST <cursor>        # with a space, annoying!
$ echo $TEST<Tab>  →  $ echo $TEST <cursor>        # same
$ echo $TEST/<Tab> →  $ echo /tmp/foo/bar/<cursor> # expands var, annoying!
```

Compare this with how e.g. tcsh does completion, which is always completing `$TES` to `$TEST/` (if `$TEST` expands to a directory-name) or to `$TEST` (if it doesn't) and never expanding anything. Which is, in my arrogant opinion, The Right Thing, and bash has it completely wrong.

So the question is obvious. Is it possible to make bash do The Right Thing too, and if so, how? I tried to understand the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Programmable-Completion.html), but without much success.

Comment: You may want to give a try to zsh. For basic usage you will probably find no differences with bash. zsh can be easily configured to do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tab completion in Bash is extremely configurable and quite complex.  If you are on Ubuntu, maybe note https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bash-completion/+bug/769866